# I'm having a problem passing a res object to my jQuery function. going from browser to mongoDB and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

Hello everyone I'm currently working on a web site and I'm trying to get the login to work. When I submit the login info its being sent as a $.get(),(I'll post code) and the info is connecting to the mongo database correctly so i know the routing is fine but my problem comes in the response. I'm able to see the data i want but I'm not able to capture it inside the callback for the $.get() and I'm not sure why.

this is my index.js:

```
          $.get("/login", {email: email.val(),password: password.val()}, function(data){

           console.log(data,"indexjs line 294");
         },"json");
```

routes.js:

```
    app.get("/login", passport.authenticate('local-login', {
 successRedirect : '/login', 
// redirect to wherever you want to go        
  failureRedirect : '/signUp' ,
// redirect back to the signup page if there is an error   
  successFlash:true,

  }),
 (req,res,)=>{
   res.send( console.log("inside get / route line 26"));
  }
);
```

passport.js:

```
    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        nameField:'name',
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        // asynchronous
        // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
        process.nextTick(function() {

            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists

         User.findOne({ 'email': email }, function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                // check to see if theres already a user with that email; uses flash module
                if (user) {

                   var newUser = new User();
                    // set the user's local credentials
                   newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                   if(!newUser.password == user.password){
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'incorrect password'));
                   }
                    else{
                        newUser.name = user.name;
                        newUser.email = user.email;
                        //console.log(newUser,"newUser in passportjs line 125");
                     return done(user);
                    }
                }
                 else {
                    // if there is no user with that email
                     return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email does not exist.'));
                }

            });

        });

    }));
```

the response I'm getting:

```
{
  _id: 5e850e5bfd081f1ed0437bdb,
  name: 'Jane Smith',
  email: 'jane@smith.com',
  password: '$2a$08$mqw45NEn52gPZ8.x0.vQh.4EvXu5Q3pRO4vFqd6dbAxuAsjm5TXxO',
  __v: 0
}
```

as you can see this is the info that I want but how do I capture it back in my index.js so that I can append an html tag with a users name. 
Any help would be much appreciated, I've been trying everything I can think of and combing through as much documentation as I can find. once i can fix this issue I'll be able to finish the rest of the login for the site.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend sending credentials via GET request. Use POST instead

Comment: _"alot of people are using Ajax and I can't for this project"_  but you are using AJAX. [Ajax > Shorthand Methods > jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I've been told before that using the shorthand was not AJAX ill edit my post.